# Batch - file renaming - A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found. error

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to renaming all the .txt.1. files to .txt and also changing the last two characters of the file name. When executing the program, even though the files are getting renamed I am receiving the error A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.

```
@Echo off

pushd &source#

set cnt=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.pgp.1) do (set /a cnt+=1)

echo(
echo File count = !cnt!
echo(
if !cnt! gtr 0 (
  for %%g in (*.txt.1) do (
    set string=%%g
    set extension=!string:~40,4!
    set "file_name=!string:~0,38!"
    set "last_two=!string:~38,2!"
    set /a add_millisec=!last_two!+1
    set add_millisec=00!add_millisec!
    set add_millisec=!add_millisec:~-2!
    set exception=10
    if !last_two! equ 99 (
       set final_string=!file_name!!exception!!extension!
       ren *.txt.1 !final_string!
    ) else (
      set final_string=!file_name!!add_millisec!!extension!
      ren *.txt.1 !final_string!
    )
    echo !final_string!
  )
) else (
echo(
echo No files to rename
echo(
)
```

Where I am going wrong, can someone please check..

Comment: A wild-haired *guess* would be that I see that you have **two** rename commands.  I see that the first represents a much less-common case ... an exception to the rule, really ... *and* I notice that the `final_string` value in that first case is **not** the same as in the second. If I were a gambler, I'd gamble that your bug is there.

Comment: Nope, changed it.. still the same result. yes, I need to replace with 10 if the last two digits are 99.
Also, it's throwing the error in a loop.. i.e. if I pass 3 files it's throwing the error 2 times for the first fie, 1 time for the second file and none for the last etc..

Comment: You are trying to rename *all* `*.txt.1` files at once to a single name: `ren *.txt.1 !final_string!`. replace `*.txt.1` by `%%g`. In general, you should place `""` around all file paths/names. And you could get the file base name by `%%~ng` and the extension by `%%~xg` rather than using substring expansion where all file names need to be equally long to work...

Comment: @aschipfl thank you, it worked.. to use %%~ng or xg I have some problem here, the extension will only give .1 and the for the file name it will also give .txt again

Comment: Sure, but you could even use another `for` loop inside the one you already have, enumerating the current item: `for %%h in ("%%~ng") do echo %%~xh` (to get the `.txt` extension)...